# Problem on Complex numbers involving a point on a Circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Question: The Complex number $z$ is represented by the point $T$ in the Argand Diagram.Given that $$z =\frac{1}{3+it}$$ where $t$ is a variable, show that

i) as $t$ varies, $T$ lies on a circle, and state the coordinates of the centre of this circle.

The only thing I did was put $z =\frac{1}{3+it}$ into the form $z =\frac{3}{9+t^2}-\frac{t}{9+t^2}i$ by multipliying $z$ by it's conjugate, but I dont know where to go from there.Help anyone?

Comment: Assuming that $T$ indeed lies on a circle, can you see that that circle is symmetric with respect to the real axis? Hence what do you know about the centre of the circle? Now try to see where the centre is, then it's routine verification.

Comment: Let $w = 3+it$ be a complex variable. This is represented by a vertical line in the complex plane going through $x=3$.

What happens to $z$ as $t \to 0$? What happens to $z$ as $t \to \pm \infty$? What do you know about mappings of the form $z = \frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$?

Comment: I'd have mentioned that $t$ is _real_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If you find three points on the circle, e.g. when $t=0,1,\infty$, then you can figure out which circle it is: what is the center and what is the radius.  Then you've reduced the problem to showing that every point on the curve lies at that particular distance from that particular point.  That's how I'd do it if I didn't know anything else relevant to the problem. ${}\qquad{}$